# Add Jenkins webhook to the GitHub organization level doesn't work

Tags: github, jenkins

To enable the auto build in Jenkins, the webhook need to be registered in Github. There is two places this can be registered, organization level and repository level. I found register at the org level doesn't work, but the repo level works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It actually works fine. Was using a wrong URL.

Comment: It only works for organization webhooks if your user is an 'owner'.